# Monitoring a postgresql db process with telegraf using procstat input plugin send running=0i for active running state

Tags: postgresql, systemd, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, procstat

I'm monitoring a postgresql db process with telegraf and procstat input plugin, but it's not seems to be working as expected in all machines(master and slaves).

The input plugin configuration is like below:

```
[[inputs.procstat]]
  systemd_unit = "postgresql-10.service"
```

For this process where it's running and telegraf says running=0i

[image: MainPID absent]

I can connect to the DB without problem using psql!

In another machine where telegraf says running=1i:

[image: MianPID!=0]

The only difference I can see is the absence of MainPID.
It seems that telegraf use this cmd `systemctl show postgresql-10.service | grep MainPID` to find the pid of process and get 0 when it says running=0i.

```
systemctl show postgresql-10.service | grep MainPID
GuessMainPID=yes
MainPID=0
ExecMainPID=0
```

The databases are installed with ansible playbook so there's no difference on version of postgres or the system unit file configuration.

I found this [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/3612) but couldn't figure out what to exactly do to fix it.

What is the issue and How to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Update:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep postgres
postgres_exporter.service                     enabled

systemctl list-unit-files | grep postgres
postgres_exporter.service                     enabled
postgresql-10.service                         disabled
```

Comment: Hi, per that issue a MainPID=0 means the service is not running, and that would align with what Telegraf is saying.  What do you get when you run `systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | grep postgres`?

Comment: Hello @powersj, the service is running and I can connect using psql. the above command returns 
postgres_exporter.service                     enabled
If I remove enabled it shows:
postgres_exporter.service                     enabled
postgresql-10.service                         disabled

The result is similar on machine where telegraf says running=0i or running=1i

I appreciate any help